# Automatically print to console if any social media links are found on a web page

Tags: javascript

I am looking to scrape a page for any social media links. I wrote some code but I am getting an undefined message in the console. Can anyone help? **Autistic and Dyslexic here.**

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].href.indexOf('facebook.com') > -1 || links[i].href.indexOf('instagram.com') > -1 || links[i].href.indexOf('youtube.com') > -1 || links[i].href.indexOf('twitter.com') > -1) {
        console.log(links[i].href);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of the `undefined` in the console?

Comment: your code seems to be working fine: [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1qdat1?file=index.js)

Comment: _"Autistic here."_ - this isn't all that helpful: that describes 2/3rds of the users of this website, myself included.

Comment: @Konrad https://prnt.sc/7_SqND-qj4Ni

Comment: @RyanPerez you are getting `undefined` here, because javascript in console works in REPL mode. for loop is treated as an expression which returns `undefined`

Comment: I don't know why you don't get any urls in the console, because it works fine for me on that site